# Drools: how to get a list with items with unique ids

Tags: list, unique, drools, items

I have a complex object in Drools.
Object A contains a list of objects B.
Object B contains a list of objects C.

Object C has a property id.  Object Cs can occur on different object Bs with the same id.

I need to be able to count the number of unique ids in A.

My current rule works when the id is not repeated.  But how do I get a listOfC without duplicate ids?

```
rule CountCs
    dialect "mvel"
    when
       a : A( )

       listOfC: List( ) from accumulate (
           b : B( ) from a.bItems
           and
           c : C( ) from b.cItems;
           collectList( c )
       )
       eval( listOfC > 2)
    then
       // do whatever
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in the number of occurrences, and not in the occurrences themselves, then you can use a `Set` to collect your ids. The `Set` will take care of eliminating the duplicates for you (assuming your ids implement the corresponding identity and equality checks):

```
rule CountCs
dialect "mvel"
when
 a : A( )
 setOfC: Set( size > 2 ) from accumulate (
   b : B( ) from a.bItems
   and
   c : C( ) from b.cItems;
   collectSet( c.id )
 )
then
  // do whatever
end
```

Note that I included the evaluation of the size of the set in the same pattern. You don't need to use an extra `eval` for that.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I believe I can add the equals() and hashCode() for this entity but will need to check the rest of the code.

Comment: I would be really interested in a more generic solution.  This style of rule is going to come up frequently in our system.  Gather a list of objects and then pull out some of them into another list, based on the value of one or more fields.  I think I need a Map or similar but in Drools I have not be able to combine a Map with the initial gathering of objects into a list.

Comment: One option could be to create your own library of "custom accumulate functions" for your specific needs. You can read more about pluggable accumulate functions in this section of the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_accumulate_ce_preferred_syntax